# Is there a way to cancel all operations in the queue?

Tags: rxandroidble

I'm writing an app using RxAndroidBle library (which is great) but due to a requirement of the Device vendor we must be able to cancel all operations after the device has reached a certain state. Is there a way of cancelling any read/write op that has been sent to the RxBleConnection?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library uses an internal [ConnectionOperationQueue](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle/blob/master/rxandroidble/src/main/java/com/polidea/rxandroidble2/internal/serialization/ConnectionOperationQueueImpl.java#L110) which tries to remove operations that have not yet reached execution state. A concrete implementation would vary case-to-case but using `RxJava` it should be fairly easy to achieve:

```
// First create a completable that will fulfil appropriately
Completable deviceReachedACertainState = ...;

// Then use it for every operation that you want to cancel (unsubscribe) when a certain state happens
Observable<byte[]> cancellableRead = rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(UUID).takeUntil(deviceReachedACertainState);
```

Keep in mind that operations that were already taken off the queue for execution will not be cancelled.

Comment: Excellent! I was thinking of doing something similar with a Publish Subject (which in fact I just did...) Thank you so much! I can't upvote because I don't have enough points...